# Problemas para querer compilar un proyecto de ionic en otra maquina con diferente versión de node js

Tags: nodejs, ionic

En una laptop con windows tengo node js en version 12.13.1 y en una mac tengo la versión 13.8.0 el problema surge cuando paso el proyecto de ionic 4 a la mac y me tira error como el " ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code -13). Alguien sabe como solucionarlo, ya intente instalar la misma version de windows a la mac pero me tira más errores y luego no se puede borrar el node

Comment: ¿Qué errores te arroja?

Comment: Esto: [Error] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code -13)   cuando hago ionic serve en la mac

Comment: Te sugiero usar [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) (Node Version Manager). Es muy fácil configurar y te permite instalar cualquier versión de Node existente. De esta forma puedes tener en tu equipo la versión más actual y la versión específica de tu aplicación, y puedes elegir cuál usar con un simple comando. Saludos